# Value of $ \binom{47}{4}+\sum_{j=1}^{5}\binom{52-j}{3}$ Using Combinatorial Identities.

Tags: combinatorics

> $(a)\;\;$ If $2\leq r \leq n\;,$ Then  $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r}+2\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}=$
>
> $(b)\;\; $ The value of $\displaystyle \binom{47}{4}+\sum_{j=1}^{5}\binom{52-j}{3} = $

$\bf{My\; Solution::(a)}$ We Can write it as $$\displaystyle \left\{\underbrace{\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}}+\underbrace{\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom{n}{r-2}}\right\}$$

Now we use the formula $$\displaystyle \binom{x}{y}+\binom{x}{y-1} = \binom{x+1}{y}.$$

So We get $$\displaystyle \binom{n+1}{r}+\binom{n+1}{r-1} = \binom{n+2}{r}.$$

$\bf{My\; Solution:: (b)}$ We Can Write it as $$\displaystyle \underbrace{\binom{47}{4}+\binom{47}{3}}+\binom{48}{3}+\binom{49}{3}+\binom{50}{3}+\binom{51}{3}$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \displaystyle \binom{x}{y}+\binom{x}{y-1} = \binom{x+1}{y}.$$

So we Get $\displaystyle \binom{52}{4}.$

My question is how can we solve above questions Using $\bf{Combinatorial \; Identities}$

Help me plz, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the identity that you have used is a combinatorial identity. There is a very simple combinatorics proof for that.

Assume that we have $m+1$ objects called $a_0, \dots, a_m$ and we want to select $n$ objects out of them. There are $\binom {m+1}{n}$ ways to do this.

This selection can be done in two ways. Either we include the first element in our selection or not. If we include the first element we are left with selecting $n-1$ objects out of the remaining $m$ elements that can be done in $\binom{m}{n-1}$ ways. If we do not include the first element we need to select $n$ objects out of the remaining $m$ elements that can be done in $\binom {m}{n}$ ways. Therefore we have,

$$
\binom {m+1}{n} = \binom {m}{n-1} + \binom{m}{n}
$$

Comment: "inequality" should read "identity"?

Comment: Thanks @hypergeometric. I edited :)

Answer (score 1):

**Part (a)**

Your approach looks fine.

For visual display, the following have been arranged according to their positions in Pascal's triangle and assigned names $A$ to $F$.

> $$\begin{align}
> &\boxed{A=\binom n{r-2}}
>    & &\boxed{B=\binom n{r-1}}
>        &   &\boxed{C=\binom nr}\\
> & &\boxed{D=\binom {n+1}{r-1}} 
>      & &\boxed{E=\binom {n+1}{r}}\\
> & & &\boxed{F=\binom {n+2}{r}}
> \end{align}$$

From $\displaystyle \binom ni+\binom n{i+1}=\binom {n+1}{i+1}$ we have

$$A+B=D\\
B+C=E\\
D+E=F$$

Hence $C+2B+A=E+D=F$, i.e. 
$$\binom n{r}+2\binom n{r-1}+\binom n{r-2}=\binom {n+2}r\qquad\blacksquare$$

**Part (b)**

We know that $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^n \binom ra=\binom {n+1}{a+1}$.

Using the above and also substituting $r=52-j$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\binom{47}{4}+\sum_{j=1}^{5}\binom{52-j}{3}
&=\sum_{r=0}^{46}\binom r3+\sum_{r=47}^{51}\binom r3\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{51} \binom r3\\
&=\binom {52}4\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$